# Push button under dynamically added select-boxes

Tags: css, html

I have a button with a function that adds selectboxes to the page. I have a H1 with some text, a button, and boxes that are added above the button. I want the button the be right under the H1, but when I add selectboxes it will be pushed down.

This is what is currently happening, the button follows the select-boxes:

[image: Selectboxes and button]

**CSS**

```
#interesses select{  
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #d8d8d8 #d1d1d1 #c3c3c3;
  border-radius: 1%;
  width:30%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0%;
  font-size: 18px;
  float: left;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
   line-height: 1.5;
   height: 38px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
#interesses-option{
  float:left;
  display: block;
  position:inline;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.wide-button-thin{
  width: 30%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #494d59;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #d8d8d8 #d1d1d1 #c3c3c3;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fefefe, #eeeeee);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
```

It works if I insert two `<br>` before the button, but I didn't get it to work with `margin-top`. Any suggestions what I could try?

**EDIT:**
Here are jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DWtPt/

Comment: Can you provide a live demo? (jsFiddle or any other alternative)

Comment: Try making the button block level and then give a `margin-top`

Comment: Please post js code. The selects should be added after the button in the dom.

Comment: the language is in norwegian , but here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DWtPt/ @antithesis

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you should only move the button code above the interesser id like this:

`<div id="velg-interesse">
     <h2>Legg til interessene dine under:</h2>
     <input type="button" class="wide-button-thin" id="leggtilInteresse" value="Legg til interesse">
    <div id="interesser"></div>
    </div>`

Comment: but the it just do the same to everything under the div

Comment: I have edited your JSfiddle and seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/DWtPt/1/ Is this the desired behavior?